# I met a man the other day who says he knows you

Tags: relative-clauses, noun-phrases

> (1) *I met a **man** the other day **who says he knows you**.*

H&P's CGEL (Page 1066) shows this sentence in a subsection called **Postposing of relative clause**, which starts like this:

> It is also possible, however, for the relative clause to occur in postposed position, at the end of the clause containing its antecedent.

In the above example, the relative clause *who says he knows you* is separated from its antecedent *man* by the intervening adjunct *the other day*, without which the sentence would be:

> (2) *I met* [<sub>NP</sub> *a **man who says he knows you***].

Here, the entire bracketed portion forms a noun phrase (NP) having the noun *man* as its head.

What is the NP having the noun *man* as its head in (1)? Is it just *a man* because the relative clause is separated by *the other day*? Or is it still *a man who says he knows you* even though it's separated by *the other day*?

Please do not post your personal opinion as an answer. Be sure to cite some authoritative source such as a grammar or a paper in your answer. (I don't think CGEL says anything about this issue, but if it does, please let me know.)

Comment: This is what's known elsewhere as Extraposition from NP. [Page 25 on this list](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Preliminarybufattenedlistoftransformations.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for the terminology, which I find very helpful in researching the issue.

Comment: @JohnLawler Are these also examples of what are called "dangling modifiers"? Grammatically, "who says he knows you" could be modifying "day", although that doesn't make sense semantically.

Comment: No, these aren't "dangling modifiers". Those are subjectless participial clauses with unclear subject reference, like _Sitting on a fence, my grandmother saw six cats_.

Comment: What could 'the other day' change, any more than 'wearing green' or 'riding a bicycle'?